# IOS8 Safari scrolling content cut off

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ios8, mobile-safari

I have an Angular website with a Bootstrap theme built primarily for mobile and on IOS8 Safari it randomly cuts off scrolling content(See image).

I have tried to inspect element when it does this but the CSS is not affecting this, and it only happens sporadically. Chrome, Opera and every other browser on IOS8 works great, it's only happening on Safari.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Thanks

[image]

CSS for the scrollable content

```
.scrollable{
 overflow: auto;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 position: absolute;
 top: 47px;
 bottom: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 }
```

Comment: Please post a complete live example using e.g. [snippets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or JS Bin.

Comment: Very odd, what is the parent of the .scrollable div? Does it have position relative? Try this on the body if that is the parent.

Comment: @Christina The parent had absolute, I tried changing to relative but the problem still occurs. Body is set to relative. Thanks

Comment: For anyone in the same predicament, Safari on IOS8 has an issue with transitions. IF you remove those all should be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A developer at work managed to solve this issue by removing transitions between pages. See the code he commented out below. It was found in controllers.js. Hopefully this example will help you find the transition code in your project.

```
$scope.slide = '';
$rootScope.back = function() {

//$scope.slide = 'slide-right';
 $window.history.back();
}
$rootScope.go = function(path){
//$scope.navLeft = false;
//$scope.navRight = false;
//$scope.slide = 'slide-left';
$location.url(path);
}
```